# Python 3 will not read appended data to file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write binary data to a file. the program will check first if the file exists. If the file does not exist, the program will create the file and write data into it. While if it does exist the data will be appended to the file. Yet, when ever i try to read the file I cannot read the appanded data only the data written when the file was first created.

```
def getText(self):
    self.readKey()
    st = self.inBox.get('1.0', 'end')

    fen = Fernet(self.readKey())
    encrypted = fen.encrypt(st.encode())
    return encrypted

def writeFile(self):

    if (os.path.exists('data.txt') == False):
        file = open('data.txt',mode='wb' )
        file.write(self.getText())
        file.close()
    else:
        file = open('data.txt',mode='ab' )
        #sts = file.read()


        file.write(self.getText())
        file.close()


    self.inBox.delete('1.0','end')




def openFile(self):
    self.outBox.delete('1.0','end')

    fen = Fernet(self.readKey())     

    try:
        f = open("data.txt", mode='rb')
    except:
        alert_popup(self,'Error','No File Exists')


    self.outBox.insert(tk.END, fen.decrypt(f.read()))
```

Comment: Where are you trying to read the appended data?

Comment: Under the method openFile(self)

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the functions?

Comment: self.dyc = tk.Button(self,text="Decrypt",command=self.openFile)
 self.dyc.grid(row = 1, column = 2, pady = 2)

Comment: Ok, but this code does not include the call to writeFile. Do you first call the openFile or the writeFIle method?

Comment: writeFile is called before openFile

Answer (score -1):

Use mode 'a'.

```
if (os.path.exists('data.txt') == False):
    file = open('data.txt',mode='a' )
    file.write(self.getText())
    file.close()
```